# jquery closure are not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            p { margin: 4px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bolder;cursor:pointer; }
            .blue { color:blue; }
            .highlight { background:red; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="blue">Click to toggle (<span>clicks: 0</span>)</p>
        <p class="blue highlight">highlight (<span>clicks: 0</span>)</p>
        <p class="blue">on these (<span>clicks: 0</span>)</p>
        <p class="blue">paragraphs (<span>clicks: 0</span>)</p>

        <script>
            var count = 0;
            $("p").each(function() {
                var $thisParagraph = $(this);
                var count = 0;
                $thisParagraph.click(function() {
                    count++;
                    $thisParagraph.find("span").text('clicks: ' + count);
                    $thisParagraph.toggleClass("highlight", count % 3 == 0);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is function assigned to click event of all the paragraph elements are  closure. So on click on the first paragraph element the var counter increases. When the user clicks on the second paragraph the counter variable should display 2, isn't it? But it is displaying 1.i m interested on why this is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined `var count` twice. Leave out the one INSIDE the `$("p").each(function(){...})`. That `var` inside there makes the variable local to that function.

Comment: what happens when i declare var count twice ,closure will refer to the var in the scope in which it was declared

Comment: That's not really closure. Defining the variable inside the `.each()` using `var` causes that variable to be treated as a private member variable.

Comment: @Maizere: If you declare a variable in an outer scope and an inner scope and reference it in an inner scope, the declaration in the inner scope takes precedence over the outer scope's declaration.

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the problem you describe is what mrunion said: you're redefining `count` as a local variable. However, you can also simplify your code a lot and get rid of the `.each` loop:

```
<script>
var count = 0;
$("p").click(function() {
    count++;
    var $thisParagraph = $(this);
    $thisParagraph.find("span").text('clicks: ' + count);
    $thisParagraph.toggleClass("highlight", count % 3 == 0);
});
</script>
```

Comment: what happens when i declare var count twice ,closure will refer to the var in the scope in which it was declared –

Comment: Every function creates a new scope. If you declare `var` again inside a function, you shadow any closured variable with the same name from an outer scope. Your function will use the local one instead.

Comment: which var will the closure refer to

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you're confused about. If you redefine a variable inside a function you lose access to any outer, closured variable with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p").each(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $(this).click(function () {
        count++;
        $(this).find("span").text('clicks: ' + count);
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight", count % 3 == 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think `$.proxy` is necessary here?